# AWS AppSync over websockets for query, mutation, and subscription (no REST)?

Tags: websocket, graphql, aws-appsync

I've been successful with Apollo Server + graphql-ws for using a websocket as the entire network transport (all queries, mutations, and subscriptions).  Is this possible to do with AWS AppSync?  Or does AWS AppSync only allow use of the websocket for subscriptions and all queries/mutations go via REST requests?

Allowing queries and mutations to go over the websocket (which is already connected for subscriptions) opens up a lot of doors for very quick two way communication between web and mobile clients.